# Symfony5 SQS consumer invalid access key

Tags: php, amazon-sqs, symfony5, phpdotenv

I'm trying to consume messages from SQS with the symfony 5 SQS consumer and i'm having an issue when the aws secret key contains special chars like `+` or `\`.

Here's my `.env` file :

```
MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN="https://sqs.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXX/bonobo-asg?access_key=XXXX&secret_key=XXXX+XXXXX\XXXXXX&region=eu-west-3&auto_setup=false"
```

And my `messenger.yml` config file :

```
framework:
    messenger:
        transports:
            asg:
                dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                serializer: App\Messenger\SnsSerializer
```

When i launch the consumer i get the following error :

```
[AsyncAws\Core\Exception\Http\ClientException (403)]                                                                                                                                   
  HTTP 403 returned for "https://sqs.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/".                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                         
  Code:    SignatureDoesNotMatch                                                                                                                                                         
  Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for de  
  tails.
```

I think it comes from the special chars in the secret key because when i try with another key containing only letters and numbers, it works fine.

I tried to escape the special chars with `\` but it gives me the same error.

How can i use my key containing special chars with the symfony sqs consumer?

Comment: I can confirm this issue. Have you checked for or opened an issue in github?  I may carve out some time to work  on fixing it if nobody is already on it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but found out that Symfony's DSN are parsed as normal URLs.

So if your URL parameters (in our case `access_key` or `secret_key`) contains some special characters, they need to be URL encoded.

I replaced `+` by `%2B` and `/` by `%2F` and it worked perfectly.

Reference: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/32021